# $\rm kg$ is to symbol, as kilogram is to unit as mass is to what?

Tags: mass, dimensional-analysis, si-units

I'm sure this has a very obvious answer but I can't even work out how to properly phrase the question.

How do you collectively define what mass, temperature, and area actually are?

For example, $\rm kg$, $\rm^\circ C$, $\rm ha$ are all symbols. Kilogram, degree Celsius, and hectare are all units. Mass, temperature, area are all what?

Comment: I've deleted some comments that were answering the question. Please keep in mind that comments are meant for suggesting improvements and requesting clarifications on their parent post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question properly, the answer is *physical dimension*, in the sense of [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).

The idea which I believe you're expressing is that kilograms and milligrams are different units which correspond to the same "kind" of physical quantity - that is, they both have dimensions of mass.

Comment: Yes thank you! I was really struggling with how to ask it as a question. Do you have any recommendations on how to refine the question to make it more easily searchable for other people?

Comment: Area would not normally be referred to as a physical dimension.

Comment: @RobJeffries but could I still refer to it as simply a dimension? Even though it is technically the product of 2 individual dimensions

Comment: You could. But referring to it as a physical quantity is what most people would do, reserving the label of physical dimensions for mass, length, time, temperature and current.

Comment: Ok makes sense. As I asked J.Murray do you have any recommendations for how to rephrase the question?

Comment: @RobJeffries I'm a bit puzzled by what you mean, I frequently use the phrase "X has dimensions of area."  It's not conventionally used as a *base* dimension, insofar as it is typically expressed as a length squared, but that doesn't make it less of a dimension of its own.  After all, I could always consider area to be a base dimension and say that length is the square root of area.

Comment: Put a different way, physical dimensions form a vector space over the rational numbers, and a choice of base dimensions amounts to a choice of a basis.  A physical dimension corresponds to an element of the space, not just the basis (which is, after all, more or less arbitrary).  I'm not trying to argue, as this is ultimately a question of terminology, but I've never seen the term "physical dimension" be restricted to *base* dimensions.

Comment: @PaulBarr Perhaps something referring to "sets of equivalent units" or something along those lines?

Comment: @J.Murray Do you? I say area has dimensions of length squared, not that area has dimensions of area.

Comment: @RobJeffries Yes. I would also say that the dimension of the surface charge density on the outside of an electrical conductor is charge divided by area, not current times time divided by length squared.  Different strokes for different folks, but I pick my basis to suit my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Mass is a fundamental physical quantity.Mass is a fundamental scalar quantity which is a measure of the amount of matter.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the 2 other answers , I believe mass isnt a quantity (12.5 is a quantity) and it's not necessarily a dimension either (unless you choose it to be so).

Mass, temperature, area are [physical properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_property)